# Play framework Scala: Create infinite source using scala akka streams and keep Server sent events connection open on server

Tags: scala, akka-stream, server-sent-events, playframework-2.6

We have requirement to implements **server sent events** for following uses cases:

1. Send notification to UI after some processing on server. This processing is based on some logic
2. Send notification to UI after reading messages from RabbitMQ followed by performing some operation on it.

Technology set we are  using Scala(2.11/2.12) with Play framework(2.6.x).
Library: **akka.stream.scaladsl.Source**

We started our proof of concept with following example https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-streaming-example and then we extended by creating different sources.
We tried creating source using Source.apply,soure.single.

**But as soon as all elements in source has been pushed to UI, my event streams got closed. But I don't want event stream to close**. Also I don't want to use some timer(Source.tick) or Source.repeat.

When my source was created, collection had let's say some x elements and then service added 4 more elements. But after x elements, event stream got closed and then again reopened.

Is there any way my event stream can be infinite and will be closed only my session is logged off or we can explicitly close it.

//Code for KeepAlive(as asked in comments)

```
   object NotficationUtil {

      var userNotificationMap = Map[Integer, Queue[String]]()

      def addUserNotification(userId: Integer, message: String) = {
        var queue = userNotificationMap.getOrElse(userId, Queue[String]())
        queue += message
        userNotificationMap.put(userId, queue)

      }

      def pushNotification(userId: Integer): Source[JsValue, _] = {
        var queue = userNotificationMap.getOrElse(userId, Queue[String]())
         Source.single(Json.toJson(queue.dequeueAll { x => true }))
      }
    }
    @Singleton
    class EventSourceController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) with FlowFactory{

      def pushNotifications(user_id:Integer) = Action {
      val stream = NotficationUtil.pushNotification(user_id)
       Ok.chunked(stream.keepAlive(50.second, ()=>Json.obj("data"->"heartbeat")) via EventSource.flow).as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM)
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to create actorref and publisher

```
val (ref, sourcePublisher)= Source.actorRef[T](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.fail).toMat(Sink.asPublisher(true))(Keep.both).run()
```

And create your source from this publisher

```
val testsource = Source
      .fromPublisher[T](sourcePublisher)
```

And register your listener as

```
Ok.chunked(
        testsource.keepAlive(
          50.seconds,
          () => Json.obj("data"->"heartbeat")) via EventSource.flow)
      .as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM)
      .withHeaders("X-Accel-Buffering" -> "no", "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache")
```

Send your json data to ref actor and data will flow as event stream through this source to front end.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot.Have you evaluated ActorPublisher as well.I was trying to identify which is better approach . Do you have any idea/suggestions. Also how we handle closing of stream in actorRef. And have you have handled this actor ref streaming per user.

Comment: No i have not used ActorPublisher.  Stream closes when there is any error or you explicitly close it from front end using close(). As stream closes, actor also gets terminated. I have been using this almost for more than 6 months, it works fine.

Comment: What about security in case of SSE? I am unable to send JWT token in my SSE request from client to server and I am facing issues on how to validate if this is a correct user trying to establish a stream. Any thoughts?
Also in our deployment topology we have an NGINX server that intercepts the request to this domain and redirects the calls to apt modules, would SSE work in that case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623232/eventsource-and-basic-http-authentication..... Also it works perfectly fine with NGINX.

Comment: @abhinavsingh : Can you please share unit test cases for above code snippet.

Comment: @abhinavsingh: we have scenario where message source emitting faster than buffer size and because of overflow strategy, messages are lost.Have u faced similar issue. How have u handled those scenario